# How to force Python's "import" to treat name as a module, not a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm using SymPy, and encountering the following problem:

```
>>> import sympy.utilities.lambdify
>>> sympy.utilities.lambdify
<function lambdify at 0x0000000003802B38>
```

Wait, shouldn't `sympy.utilities.lambdify` be a module?

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function
>>> implemented_function
<function implemented_function at 0x0000000003802CF8>
>>> implemented_function.__module__
'sympy.utilities.lambdify'
```

Oh, so there's a naming conflict.

Now obviously I can just use `implemented_function`, but that's not my question.

My question is: how can I import the `sympy.utilities.lambdify` **module** rather than the *function*?

(I just used SymPy for illustration here. Whether or not this is proper library usage is beside the point. The source is [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/master/sympy/utilities).)

Comment: Cant you do just `from sympy.utilities import lambdify` ?

Comment: @KarthikRavindra: `>>> from sympy.utilities import lambdify`
`>>> lambdify`
`<function lambdify at 0x0000000003802B38>`

Comment: Yes, i agree, but the thing is, looking at the source code, [lambdify](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/utilities/lambdify.py#L178) is not a module. It is a file inside a package

Comment: That seems like a very poor layout design, if the `lambdify` module is in fact intended to be imported. I suspect it is not possible to nicely do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KarthikRavindra: I'm confused, if it's not a module, then why is it the value of `implemented_function.__module__`...?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't specific to how sympy is structured?

Comment: @lxop: Well, it's hard to say, because `implemented_function` is indeed intended to be used, but maybe they always intended it to be used directly instead of through its module (er, package?)... which I agree is still poor design.

Comment: @innisfree: You could structure anything else the same way and get the same effect, so I don't get your point or what difference it makes. My question is how to force the import to be of a module (er... package?). I don't really care what's causing this.

Comment: @KarthikRavindra a file inside a package is a module.

Comment: It certainly looks like the sympy devs intend for the functions in that module to be imported directly, unfortunately.

Comment: @lxop: OK, but regardless of their intentions, is there any way to do what I'm asking? Or no?

Comment: Yes, but this sympy structure could be rather idiosyncratic/specific to sympy, so if you're writing your own code and don't want it that way, don't do it that way.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't believe there is - `lambdify` in the `utilities` namespace is the function, not the module, so you'll just have to do direct imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it looks like this can be done quite cleanly with importlib:

```
import importlib
lamdify = importlib.import_module('sympy.utilities.lambdify')
print lambdify
  <module 'sympy.utilities.lambdify' from 'c:\python-2.7.8-amd64\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\lambdify.pyc'>
```

EDIT from comments (thanks @Mehrdad):

Alternatively, if you want to avoid putting module names in strings, you could do this:

```
def import_module(lambda_): 
    import importlib; 
    return importlib.import_module('.'.join(lambda_.__code__.co_names))
```

Usage: `lambdify = import_module(lambda: sympy.utilities.lambdify)`

Though this looks a bit longer and less clear to me.

Comment: Nice catch, that does look straightforward.

Comment: +1 this looks nice too! Any idea if it's any different from the `sys.modules` solution? Any reason to prefer either one over the other?

Comment: @Mehrdad This does use `sys.modules` under the hood, but it's one clean line using a standard library (I suppose two lines if you count the import of `importlib`), so is more readable. It looks similar enough to a regular import statement that it is immediately understandable.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'd also add that importlib adds some functionality in python 2, and also that if you follow this approach, you don't have to repeat yourself (compare `import submod_name` then `sys.modules['submod_name']` in my answer).

Comment: @lxop: I figured out a way to avoid putting module names in strings (I think it's poor code). If you'd like, I suggest you add it to your answer: `def import_(lambda_): import importlib; return importlib.import_module('.'.join(lambda_.__code__.co_names))` (Usage: `lambdify = import_(lambda: sympy.utilities.lambdify)`)

Answer (score 2):

The apparent inconsistency is due to the fact that `lambdify` is not a module, it's a python file containing multiple function definitions. Consider the following example in a file called `bar.py`:

```
def foo(): pass

def bar(): pass
```

Then `from bar import bar; print(bar.__module__)` will give you `'bar'`.

The reason `lambdify` can be imported like this is the line in the `__init__` of `sympy.utilities`:

```
from .lambdify import lambdify
```

That is, in the `lambdify.py` file of the `sympy.utilities` module, there's a definition for `lambdify()`, and this is imported into the `sympy.utilities` namespace. So when you import `sympy.utilities`, you have access to lambdify. But you can still `import` other functions defined in `lambdify.py` by `from sympy.utilities.lambdify import ...`.

---

Your actual question is whether you can import a module like this. Well, *you can*, but you probably shouldn't. Let's model the situation with the above `bar.py`, and make it a package by creating an `__init__py`:

```
from .bar import bar
```

Putting these two files in the directory named `tmp`, we get a model of your scenario, with a module named `tmp` and a "submodule" `bar` (but I don't think it's a proper submodule, lacking an `__init__.py`). The same thing happens if we import `tmp.bar`, as with `sympy`:

```
>>> import tmp
>>> tmp
<module 'tmp' from '/home/user/python/tmp/__init__.py'>
>>> import tmp.bar
>>> tmp.bar
<function bar at 0x7f24426461e0>
>>> tmp.bar.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> from tmp.bar import foo
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x7f2442646158>
```

So `tmp.bar` refers to the function rather than the module. Apparently. But actually it also gives access to the module, despite it being shadowed by the function of the same name!

Let's repeat the above, but keep monitoring `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'tmp' in sys.modules
False
>>> import tmp.bar
>>> tmp.bar
<function bar at 0x7fc833025158>
>>> 'tmp.bar' in sys.modules
True
>>> tmp.bar.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> sys.modules['tmp.bar'].foo
<function foo at 0x7fc833020f28>
```

So while `tmp.bar` refers to the function in the local namespace, we can access the module itself through `sys.modules['tmp.bar']` coming from the same import.

Just to be explicit:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import sympy.utilities.lambdify
>>> lambdify_module = sys.modules['sympy.utilities.lambdify']
>>> lambdify_module.implemented_function
<function implemented_function at 0x7fc83183ca60>
```

Comment: Is this a long way of saying what I'm asking isn't possible? If so then please mention that explicitly; otherwise it's not really answering my question.

Comment: @Mehrdad I believe that is the case, yes. I'll try to come up with a small example that makes my point clearer.

Comment: @Mehrdad turns out you can do this, but I suspect it's very kludgy. I'd definitely say that the sympy devs didn't intend for you to do this; but I know your question is of a general quality.

Comment: That's clever, I didn't realize you'd be able to access it through sys.modules in that way

Comment: Haha awesome! I feel dumb now, it seems so obvious in hindsight :) thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to the structure of `sympy`. See this [line](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/utilities/__init__.py#L12) of the source code for the utilities `__init__.py`:

```
from .lambdify import lambdify
```

It imports the *function* `lambdify` from the local module `lambdify`; thus `utilities.lambdify` is the *function*.

Supposing that you wish to truly import the module, and not the function, `lambdify`. Perhaps something like,

```
import os
import imp

import sympy.utilities as mod
sub_mod_name = 'lambdify'
sub_mod_file = '{}.py'.format(sub_mod_name)

mod_loc = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
file_ = os.path.join(mod_loc, sub_mod_file)  # Full path for source file
sub_mod = imp.load_source(sub_mod_name, file_)  # Import module from source file

print sub_mod
# <module 'lambdify' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/utilities/lambdify.pyc'>
```